# How to overcome "not responding" status in a python GUI application under Windows 7?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have a python application, which uses a wxpython GUI. When it is executing a long task, in the window title it says "(Not responding)" and the cursor becomes a spinning (busy) circle. It stays that way until the execution is completed. How to overcome this "Not responding" state? It makes look my application buggy.

Comment: Do long tasks in another (not GUI) thread?

Comment: Do you mean use "threading" module?

Comment: I am not quite sure about python, but in any other language (java, c#, cpp) you have to do GUI and all other (long) tasks in different threads to avoid GUI "lag"). Remember, one thread can only update GUI or do your calculations at once, that's why your getting not responding state.

Comment: The application must read a big file, and it gets the file path from GUI input. Is threading in this case still possible? I mean the "read file" job will not start until user enters file path in the GUI.

Comment: When user inputs file, you open another thread which reads that file (to shared memory, such as main program) (reading thread should also send some status to GUI thread to draw something like loading bar)

Comment: OK thanks. How many simultaneous threads can I create max?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47633/discussion-between-valdas-and-alwbtc)